# US Travel Visa on Expired PRC Passport used with Hong Kong Passport

Tags: usa, china, hong-kong

I am a Chinese national but now a permanent resident of Hong Kong. My Chinese PRC passport is expired, but it still has a valid U.S. travel visa.

Can I enter the U.S. with a Hong Kong Passport using the U.S. visa on my expired PRC passport? Or do I have to apply for a new visa using my Hong Kong passport.

I want to avoid applying for a new visa if I don't need to.

Thanks!

P.S.: I guess the question is whether Hong Kong SAR is treated as the same country or passport type as PRC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a source for this opinion, but I'm fairly confident that the Hong Kong Passport and the PRC Passport are NOT the same country. Thus IIRC you cannot enter the US with the combination of passports you hold.

You should however be able to apply for a new visa with your HK passport and likely quickly be approved based on your existing visa - you can mention it in the application.

Timatic mentions that you require a visa on a HK passport.

If you plan to travel in the near future (I guess not if you're asking about needed visa applications) you should also adhere to following advice from Timatic:

> Passengers are only permitted to enter or transit the United States through the following airports if they have entered or transited China in the past 14 days, due to the outbreak of novel coronavirus.
>
> - John F. Kennedy International Airport (JFK),
> - Chicago O’Hare International Airport (ORD),
> - San Francisco International Airport (SFO),
> - Seattle-Tacoma International Airport (SEA),
> - Daniel K. Inouye International Airport (HNL),
> - Los Angeles International Airport, (LAX),
> - Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport (ATL),
> - Washington-Dulles International Airport (IAD),
> - Newark Liberty International Airport (EWR),
> - Dallas/Fort Worth International Airport (DFW),
> - Detroit Metropolitan Airport (DTW).